# Convert in memory bitmap image to 4 dimensional array like numpy

Tags: c#, .net, numpy, tensorflow

This is a `.NET/C#` project where I am trying to feed an image through a `Tensorflow` model using `Tensorflow.Net`. Before I can feed the image through, it must be in the form of a 4D byte array, like a numpy array or `NDArray` as Tensorflow.Net calls it. I have the following code:

```
var bitmapBytes = GetBitmapBytes(testImage);
var imgArr = NumSharp.np.array(bitmapBytes);
```

But when I run the imgArr, which is an NDArray type, through the Tensorflow model, I get the following exception:

> System.Exception: 'input must be 4-dimensional[1]      [[{{node
>   Preprocessor/map/while/ResizeImage/ResizeBilinear}}]]'

For the record, the call to `GetBitmapBytes` method is simply converting the Bitmap to byte array using `BitmapData` and lockbits, as I want some level of performance.

So, I am able to successfully convert the Bitmap to a byte array, which comes back as a 1D byte array with the appropriate length to match my images W by H. However, I need it to be a 4D array.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT:** We have released [NumSharp.Bitmap](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NumSharp.Bitmap/) which provides extensions to `System.Drawing.Bitmap`

> `> Install-Package NumSharp.Bitmap`

**From Bitmap:**

```
using NumSharp;

//from bitmap
var ndarray = bitmap.ToNDArray(flat: false, copy: false);
//ndarray.shape == (1, height, width, 3).
```

**To Bitmap:**

```
//to bitmap
var bitmap_from_ndarray = ndarray.ToBitmap(width, height);
//or
var bitmap_from_ndarray = ndarray.ToBitmap(ndarray.shape[1], ndarray.shape[2]);
```

**Original Answer:**
The following method should do that.

```
public static NDArray GetBitmapBytes(Bitmap image)
{
    if (image == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(image));

    BitmapData bmpData = image.LockBits(new Rectangle(0, 0, image.Width, image.Height), ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, image.PixelFormat);
    try
    {
        unsafe
        {
            //Create a 1d vector without filling it's values to zero (similar to np.empty)
            var nd = new NDArray(NPTypeCode.Byte, Shape.Vector(bmpData.Stride * image.Height), fillZeros: false);

            // Get the respective addresses
            byte* src = (byte*)bmpData.Scan0;
            byte* dst = (byte*)nd.Unsafe.Address; //we can use unsafe because we just allocated that array and we know for sure it is contagious.

            // Copy the RGB values into the array.
            Buffer.MemoryCopy(src, dst, nd.size, nd.size); //faster than Marshal.Copy
            return nd.reshape(1, image.Height, image.Width, 3);
        }
    }
    finally
    {
        image.UnlockBits(bmpData);
    }
}
```